¿ES POSIBLE CRHOMAR VIDEOS EN VB.NET?
PRIMERO NECESITO UN SELECTOR DE COLORES DE UN PIXEL, YA QUE EL VIDEO SE VISUALIZA EN UN PICTURE BOX, PARA VOLVER TRANSPARENTE TODOS LOS PIXELES DE ESE COLOR, YA QUE EL CONTROL ICTURE BOX PERMITE CARGAR 2 IMAGENES UNA PRINCIPAL UNA BACKIMAGE. SE UTILIZAR EL CRHOMA CON FOTOS, PERO NO SE SI FUNCIONE CON VIDEOS. ¿ALGUNA AYUDA? DESEO OBTENER EL EFECTO LLAMADO CRHOMAKEY

Creo recordad que DirectX tiene esa funcionalidad

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
